# react matching 2 arrays in output

Tags: reactjs

Ok, I am trying to do the following. I have 2 arrays:

item.values:

```
[0: value: 'ab'],
[1: value: 'cd'],
.....
```

and array:

item.choices:

```
[0: display_value: 'Abort', value: 'ab'],
[1: display_value: 'cds', value: 'cd'],
.....
```

Now I have the following existing piece of code that I need to modify:

```
const sortFunc = (a:string, b:string) => {
    const fa = a.toLowerCase(),
        fb = b.toLowerCase();
    if (fa < fb) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (fa > fb) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

item.values.sort((a, b) => sortFunc(a.value, b.value)).map((a) => {
    return (<Text key={a.value} children={a.value} />)
});
```

What I tried is the following:

```
item.values.sort((a, b) => sortFunc(a.value, b.value)).map((a) => 
    // return (<Text key={a.value} children={a.value} />)
    displayValue(a.value, item.choices)
);

const displayValue = (item: string, item2: any) => {
    if (item2 && item2.length > 0) {
        item2.map((c:any) => {
            if (item !== c.value) {
                return;
            }
            // console.log('yes', item, c.display_value);
            return <Text key={item} children={c.display_value} />
        })
    }
}
```

The console.log in my piece outputs both items (item and c.display_value) if value from item.values and item.choices match, but the return doesn't do anything, nothing is shown.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `return` from the map result:

```js
const displayValue = (item: string, item2: any) => {
    if (item2 && item2.length > 0) {
        return item2.map((c:any) => { // note the added `return`
            if (item !== c.value) {
                return;
            }
            return <Text key={item} children={c.display_value} />
            // This only returns from the callback of the `map`
        })
    }
}
```

By the way: the resulting array of this `map`ping may contain `undefined` values for the cases where the `if` condition is false. So you probably want to apply `.filter(Boolean)` to the result first before using it in React to filter out those undefined values.

Comment: Awesome nice find